All matroid polytope is a generalized permutohedron
In many texts, the authors say something like "a matroid polytope lives in the family of generalized permutohedra". We can quickly check the veracity of this claim by describing the matroid polytope $P_M$ using the inequality description of $P_M$. This description is actually given by:
$$
P_M = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = r, \sum_{i \in I} x_i \leq r(I), \forall I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\} \}
$$
where $M$ is a matroid over $[n] = \{1, \dots, n\}$ defined by its collection of bases $\mathcal{B}$ and with rank $r$.
Now, for me, it is not trivial to arrive at this definition starting from the usual definition of $P_M$, because the usual notation is:
$$
P_M = \text{conv}\{e_A : A \in \mathcal{B}\} \quad \text{with} \quad e_A = \sum_{i \in A} e_{i}.
$$
Well, maybe I can rewrite it as something like:
$$
P_M = \text{conv}\{e_A : A \in \mathcal{B}\} = \left\{\sum_{k} \lambda_{k} \left(\sum_{i \in A} e_{i} \right) : \lambda_i \geq 0, \sum \lambda_i = 1 \right\}.
$$
But how can I get the inequality description of $P_M$ using the last fact? Any hints or suggestions? I'd appreciate it.
Note:It may be that my appreciation is not entirely true, and to arrive at this description of the matroidal polytope it is not even necessary the usual definition, but I do not see clearly the way to describe what I mentioned.

See https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture15.pdf section 1.4
